# incrementing a var based on field values in AWK

Tags: awk, variable-assignment

I need to print out the number of connections rates in certain ranges from a file using AWK.

Here is a portion of the data:

```
Mon Sep 15 11:50:08 1997
        User-Name = "edvargas"
        NAS-Identifier = 207.238.228.11
        NAS-Port = 20116
        .
        .
        .
        Ascend-Connect-Progress = 60
        Ascend-Data-Rate = 31200
        .
        .
        .
```

There are 5 different ranges so I'm testing with the lowest two.
Here is what I have thus far:

```
BEGIN{first=0; second=0; third=0; fourth=0; fifth=0}
/Ascend-Data-Rate/ && ($3<14400){
        first++;
}
/Assend-Data-Rate/ && ($3>14400) && ($3<19200){
        second++;
}
END{print "first =",first, "second =",second}
```

Neither of these increment the vars.  I know that my in my output the **first** range is supposed to find 6 and the **second** is supposed to find 2.  However, neither is working right.

Here's how I understand the problem:

```
  Search each record (line) for the field (string) "Ascend-Data-Rate"

    If that is found:  then compare the value of $3 (third field) to the range.

      If that is found: increase the value of the var by one.
```

I'm 90% sure that it's the syntax that is throwing me off.  What am I missing?

This is a practice exercise to prepare me for an assignment due next week.

Comment: Version 2 of code is above and the same issue is there.  first = 1 second = 0

Comment: what if the value **equals** 14400 ??

Comment: Second was supposed to be 14401 to 19200. sorry.

Comment: that's even worse, then you're missing 2 possible values. you need the `<=` operator

Answer (score 2):

The problem is how you're increasing the vars:

First, you initialise the variable to zero.

```
first = 0
```

Then you increase the variable by it's value.  But as that value is zero, it doesn't increase.

```
first += first;
```

Basically in this context, it's the same as saying:

```
first += 0;
```

or

```
first = first + 0;
```

Just a hunch, but I think you probably want

```
first = first + 1;
```

or (means the same thing)

```
first++;
```

instead...

Comment: The first is only incrementing to "1" and second is still "0"

Comment: @Larry: There is a typo in second regex, `Assend` instead `Ascend`.

Comment: @Larry: According to the condition, `second` will only be increased if the line contains `Assend-Data-Rate` and the third value is between 14400 and 19200 (`($3>14400) && ($3<19200)`).  As the value is actually 31200 the second condition will not fire.  Try changing the value in the data file or modifying the condition.

Comment: This is what I ended up with.  The output is correct: `BEGIN{first = 0; second = 0}
/Ascend-Data-Rate/{
if ($3>=0 && $3<=14400)
first++
if ($3>14400 && $3<=19200)
second++
}
END{print "0-14400\t\t" first
print "14401-19200\t" second
}`

Comment: Thanks for the quick help today.  How do you add a new comment block similar to my first post.  I think I've seen other posts with that but I don't know how to do it.  Thanks again.

Comment: @beny23 the data is about 700 lines so I only put a few lines of the data for clarification.  Thanks.